# Why use self if code works without it?

Tags: objective-c, self

Really, why most of people use self.something for almost everything when code works without it?

for example:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

self.mylabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@", someVariable];

}
```

The code works the same way without self.

I have tried to see what happens without self and it always works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using self. means that you are using the getter/setter, and not using it means that you are accessing the instance variable directly.

This question has been treated a lot here, but summarising:

> ALWAYS create a @property for every data member and use “self.name” to
>   access it throughout your class implementation. NEVER access your own
>   instance variables directly.
>
> Properties enforce access restrictions (such as readonly)
>
> Properties enforce memory management policy (strong, weak)
>
> Properties provide the opportunity to transparently implement custom
>   setters and getters.
>
> Properties with custom setters or getters can be used to enforce a
>   thread-safety strategy. Having a single way to access instance
>   variables increases code readability.

Source:

[Best Practices fr Obj-C](http://ironwolf.dangerousgames.com/blog/archives/913)

Comment: Thanks! Still, what would be the drawback of not using self?

Comment: is it necessary to use `@synthesize`?

Comment: No drawback apart from that